# How to repopulate data when using getServerSideProps and the page allows data modification in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Lets say I have a page `example.com/user/1` that consists of a single component which I pass props to using `getServerSideProps` and thus is SSR'd. For this example lets say the props is `{"name":"Bob"}`

That page allows the user to modify the `name` value that is displayed on that page, which is updated using a standard `fetch()` call to the backend. That `fetch()` call returns the updated value (lets say `{"name":"Alice"}`), which I now would like to display on the UI.

However I can't because the component is using the props to generate the UI.

As I see it I have 3 options:

1. Force a refresh of the whole page, which would now get the updated `name` property from the `getServerSideProps` function in the backend.
2. Create a copy of the props as a local state, use that to generate the UI, and update that state value whenever the `name` is updated using `fetch()`. So something like:

```
const User = ({ name }) => {
  const [localName, setLocalName] = useState(``);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalName(name);
  }, []);

  const saveNewName = async (name) => {
    await fetch(url, {name}, etc....);
    setLocalName(name);
  }

  // Still missing the UI to enter a new name and save it to the backend!

  return <p>Hello, {localName}</p>;
}
```

3. Not use `getServerSideProps` at all, nor the component props, but instead fetch the data after the page is hydrated, like a "traditional" SPA.

Are these three approaches reasonable? Which is the better option? Is there another, better option? Thank you!

Comment: `getServerSideProps` is meant to be used so that it provides initial data to your page. You'd need to handle what you describe on the client-side, you can consider the data coming from the server as your initial state. Alternatively, there is a workaround for this described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72919096/how-can-i-refetch-with-getserversideprops-in-next-on-a-click-on-client-side/72919412#72919412). You can check it out and see if it adapts to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the link @ivanatias, that's a very similar situation as mine. Also from that code I notice that I don't need the `useEffect`... I can just set `name` as the initial state value.

Comment: The options are all viable and reasonable, it all depends on the requirements you have for that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getServerSideProps` to fetch data at request time and then have as state which get updated when the data has been changed --option 2

alternatively, you can use client side if you don’t need to pre-render the data, `SWR` is an option that handles caching, revalidation, focus tracking, refetching on intervals, and more. Check [SWR by NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)